# how to handle response and next in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, response

I was wondering how should I be dealing with response and next in express.

My understanding is that when I say res.send(...) -> returns a response

If I want to throw an error, I say next(new Error('whatever')) -> auto sets the http status code using express errorhandler.

I am able to do either of those but not but, looks like I am messing up.

Can anyone give an example?

I tried,

```
somefunc(err, req, res, next) {
    if(err) {
        res.send(500, 'some error');
        return next(err); 
    }
}

return [somefunc, express.errorHandler()];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can register some middleware to handle errors:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```

You can also simply send a 500 with your response if you encounter an error in your logic

```
function loginUser(req, res, next) {
    try {
        var valid;
        //code to check user
        if (valid) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.send(401, 'not authorized');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(500, 'Oopsy');
    }
}

app.get('/some/route',loginUser, function(req, res) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just skip `return next();` part. Use `return res.send(500,'some error');` Calling `next` causes next middleware to be called which IMO is not what you want in this case. I wrote more about it [here](http://jakub.fedyczak.net/post/express-js-internals-crash-course/).

Here is minimal example of express stack:

```
express = require('express');

app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(app.router());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (some error)
        res.send(500, 'Some error');
    else
        res.send('<body>Hello</body>');
});

app.listen(3000); // listen on port 3000
```

The get request will be called by `router` middleware. Middlewares are parsed as chain. You can use custom middleware in this chain, for example:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        if (some condition)
            res.send(500, 'No way'); // this will break the request chain
        else
            next(); // this will continue processing and will call app.router middleware
    });
    app.use(app.router());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

`app.router` middleware is responsible for calling appropriate method based on requested URL (like `app.get('/')`). If it fails to find one, it calls `next()` to pass control to `express.static` middleware which tries to find static file in `/public/` folder.

Comment: OP asks for examples.  Also, if you could explain more without using a URL that'd be better than just saying, `go here and read`.